# plotting subplots in pandas with month as index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that index is date in format(2017_01_31,....) and I have a column called 'Energy' and three other columns 'I_Base','U_Win', 'Occ'. 
I want to have a scatter plot of each with y set to be 'Energ' but for the condition that index is January. I tried the following code but its totally wrong.

```
fig, r = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(14,4))
for index, xcol, ax in zip(r.index.month==1,['U_Win', 'I_Base', 'Occ'], r):
    df.plot(kind='scatter', x=xcol, y='Energy', ax=ax, alpha=0.5, color='r')
```

Thats how my dataframe is :

```
Index          I_Base         U_Win         Energy       Occ                

2017_01_31       0.3           0.9         2.2989e+11     96          

2017_01_31       0.5           0.8         2.29892e+11    40         

....
2017_02_28       0.7           0.9         2.40001e+11    80         



....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
fig, r = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=3, figsize=(14,4))
for ax, col in zip(r, ['I_Base', 'U_Win', 'Occ']):
    df[df.index.month == 1].plot(kind='scatter', x=col, y='Energy', ax=ax, alpha=.5, color='r')
```

This will do the scatter plot where index's Datetime is Jan.

Please read this about [reproducible data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link you sent! And also thanks for the solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link you sent! And also thanks for the solution.